# Swift scrollToItem and center in middle of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have been having trouble trying to understand how to programmatically use scrollToItem in a CollectionView and center the cell in the middle of the screen. It seems that when I use scrollToItem, it scrolls to the item horizontally but then stops at the beginning of the cell that I wanted to scroll to and not in the center of it. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.cv.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height - 150) 
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
         return UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 0
     }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to scroll to the *last* cell?

Comment: Hi, No I am trying to scroll to any cell programmatically.

Comment: OK, well, a quick test shows it working fine for me... Are you running any other code? Is this in response to a button tap? After the scroll animation stops, can you still drag-scroll the cell to the horizontal center?

Comment: In which function you are calling these lines of code?

Comment: Ah - you can't do that in `viewDidLoad()` --- the auto-layout engine hasn't finished laying everything out yet. Try moving it to `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: @DonMag your right. Thank you very much